# fixed table layout resize when column is hiding

Tags: javascript, css

I have a fixed table layout with width being 425px. It is a table with 200 rows. When the user un-select the checkbox specifying the column, the column is hidden. When the column is hidden, the table is left with the space on the hidden column and the other column width is resized.
Could some one point me on the fix?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var showMode = 'table-cell';  
   if (document.all) showMode='block';  

     function toggleVis(btn) {  
         btn   = document.forms['tcol'].elements[btn];  
         cells = document.getElementsByName('t'+btn.name);  
         mode = btn.checked ? showMode : 'none';  
         for(j = 0; j < cells.length; j++)  
              cells[j].style.display = mode;  
     }
```

Also, the html and css

```
   .sortable {width: 425px;border: 2px solid #900;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout: fixed}

 .sortable th {text-align:left;border: 1px solid #fff}

 .sortable thead th.sub0 {text-align: center;color:#fff;font-size:115%;background: #88b8db repeat-x 0 -1400px;padding: 2px}

 .sortable tbody th.sub0 {text-align: center;font-size:90%;color:#000;background: #efefef repeat-x 0 -100px;padding: 5px}

 .sortable tbody th.sub1 {word-wrap:break-word;text-align: left;font-size: 90%;color: #000;background: #efefef repeat-x 0 -100px;padding: 6px}
```

```
   <table class="sortable" id="table_id">

   <col width="45">

   <col width="180">

   <col width="200">

   <thead>

   <tr>

   <th class="sub0"  id="tcol1">ID

   <th class="sub0"  id="tcol2">File Name

   <th class="sub0"  id="tcol3">Path

  </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </table>

  <br/>

  <form name="tcol" onsubmit="return false">

           Show Columns

  <input type=checkbox name="col1" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Id

<input type=checkbox name="col2" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> File Name

 <input type=checkbox name="col3" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Path

 </form>
```

Thanks, 
Karthik

Comment: What is the desired result you would like? Re-size all columns according to new available total width?

Comment: Thanks, Since the table has border, i need to get rid of the space. Instead, i can have the last column adjust the remaining size of the layout. I am not sure to implement the same.

Comment: Anyway, I have to get rid of the space on the right side of the table. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cells = document.getElementsByName('t'+btn.name)`

look:

```
<th class="sub0"  id="tcol1">ID

<th class="sub0"  id="tcol2">File Name

<th class="sub0"  id="tcol3">Path
```

You got **id** there not **name**

It won't do what you want anyway.

EDIT

This works for me:

```
<style>
  table { width: 425; background-color: #eee;}
  td, th { background-color: #ddd} 
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleVis(btn)
{
  var col = btn.name.substring(3);
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName ( "tr" );
  if ( btn.checked )
  {
    for ( var i=0; i < tr.length; i ++)
    {
      tr[i].childNodes[col-1].style.display = "table-cell";
    }
  }
  else
  {   
    for ( var i=0; i < tr.length; i ++)
    {
      tr[i].childNodes[col-1].style.display = "none";     
    }
  }
}   
</script>

<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr><th class="sub0"  id="tcol1">ID</th><th class="sub0"  id="tcol2">File Name</th><th class="sub0"  id="tcol3">Path</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>file_0</td><td>dir_0/file_0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>file_1</td><td>dir_1/file_1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>file_2</td><td>dir_2/file_2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>file_3</td><td>dir_3/file_3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>

<form name="tcol" onsubmit="return false">
  Show Columns
  <input type=checkbox name="col1" onclick="toggleVis(this)" checked="checked"/>Id
  <input type=checkbox name="col2" onclick="toggleVis(this)" checked="checked"/>File Name
  <input type=checkbox name="col3" onclick="toggleVis(this)" checked="checked"/>Path
</form>
```

I do not break lines inside `<tr></tr>` due to white-spaces, because they count as child nodes.

Comment: I missed the name it is actually,

Comment: <th class="sub0" name="tcol1" id="tcol1">ID

Comment: Look at my code. Table is 425px wide. If any column is not displayed, rest fill the empty space.

Comment: Thanks, the code works. Let me try the sample code to expand to large table width to 1250px with 11 columns and 300 rows.